# Java / PayPal integration points to wrong endpoint

Tags: java, api, maven, paypal, integration

My Paypal integration stopped working on 9/13/12 with my Java application. I did some research and found a similar question here in 
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412547/paypal-sandbox-api-ssl-handshake-error-suddenly-started-using-paypal-php-sdk) as I was getting the same errors "handshake_failure". Debugging, I see that the endpoint was defined as "api.sandbox..." while the documentation says "api-3t.sandbox..."

Now I am not sure how all of this changed or what. I believe to be using the API Signature method of credential verification (I have no certificates). Calling PayPal tech support has only caused me to run in circles and I am looking for a solution.

I am running Java with Maven integrating with paypal_base.4.3.56 and paypal_stubs.4.3.56. Am I needing to upgrade my libraries? Did something change that I need to alter my code? Can I use the same libaries and change the endpoint values?

Comment: Apparently the "similar question" has the answer, added very recently, and the "fix" is on the way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PayPal Sandbox API SSL handshake error suddenly started using PayPal PHP SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412547/paypal-sandbox-api-ssl-handshake-error-suddenly-started-using-paypal-php-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct PayPal sandbox endpoint URL is http://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/.

A user who encountered a similar issue reported it as a bug; you can find further information in [the report](https://github.com/paypalx/SDKs/issues/22).

Comment: yes, a bug. however his fix was to change his PHP config file (easy enough).. I'm using Java against a MAven dependency of paypal_base4.3.56... I don't know what my fix would be

Comment: @follow up
Paypal support says they did not change servers, yet my libs have not been touched in over 2 years. Anyway, the API does say to point the "3t" endpoints so I unpacked the jar file, changed the wsdl definition and packed it back up again. This seemed to work.

I didn't want to download the new SDK becasue the code base has changed and would require me to refactor my code. What I had to do was an acceptable change